# Why I am not able call a method from another method in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Please check the below code

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const stripe = require('stripe')(prop.get('stripe.secret_key'));

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.createStripeAccountLink = async (event, context) => {

    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    connection.config.namedPlaceholders = true;

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;


    const params = event.queryStringParameters;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        return response;
    }


    let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
    console.log("body", body);

    let countryCode = body.countryCode;
    let userId = body.userId;
    let isStripeExists = false;
    let stripeAccountId;

    if (countryCode == null || userId == null) {
        return errorCodes.missing_parameters;
    }

    if (isNaN(userId)) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_fields;
        return response;
    }

    try {

        console.log("countryCode: ", countryCode);

        await connection.beginTransaction();

        //Check whether an account is registered for this user
        let stripeDataSql = "SELECT * FROM stripe WHERE iduser = ?";
        const [stripeData, stripeMeta] = await connection.query(stripeDataSql, [userId]);
        console.log(stripeData);

        if (stripeData.length==0) {
            isStripeExists = false
        } else {
            if (stripeData[0].account_id == null) {
                isStripeExists = false
            } else {
                console.log("account found: ", stripeData[0].account_id);
                isStripeExists = true;
            }
        }

        const account = await createStripeAccount();
        const accountLink = await createStripeLink(account.id, userId);
        console.log("url: ", accountLink.url);


        //Commit and complete
        await connection.commit();

        var response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "account_link": accountLink.url
            }),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        if(error.toString().includes("pe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required"))
        {
            //The link was created before but it is not clicked. Recreate the link.
        }
        //await connection.rollback();
        return errorCodes.save_failed;
    } finally {
        //connection.release();
    }


};

async function createStripeAccount()
{
    //Create stripe account
    const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
        country: countryCode,
        type: 'express',
        capabilities: {
            card_payments: {
                requested: true
            },
            transfers: {
                requested: true
            }
        },
        business_type: 'individual',
    });

    return account;
    

}

async function createStripeLink(stripeAccountId,userId)
{
    //Create stripe account link
    const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
        account: stripeAccountId,
        refresh_url: ``,
        return_url: ``,
        type: 'account_onboarding',
    });

    return accountLink;
}
```

What you saw above is an AWS Lambda function. When I run my code I get the below error.

```
 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)source/stripe/create-stripe-account-link.js:78:31)d
END RequestId: 590f7b6b-03c5-45bb-8428-b29da9fb14bc
```

This is exactly where I have the following code lines

```
const account = await createStripeAccount();
        const accountLink = await createStripeLink(account.id, userId);
        console.log("url: ", accountLink.url);
```

If I take the content in `createStripeAccount` and `createStripeLink` right inside of the function `exports.createStripeAccountLink`, my code works fine.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you try defining those two functions above the main lambda handler?

Comment: What you quoted isn't the error message! It's the description of where the error occurred. The error message should appear just **before** that in your output.

Comment: @Brian that is irrelevant due to hoisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. My method `createStripeAccount()` was using a field called `countryCode` which is undefined. So I had to make this method accept it as a parameter.